# How can I upload package for several ubuntu versions to Launchpad automatically?

Tags: ppa, package-management, launchpad, packaging

See the title.

I using dput and in my /etc/dput.cf :

```
[ppa]
fqdn        = ppa.launchpad.net
method      = ftp
incoming        = ~onto/onto/ubuntu/
login           = anonymous
allow_unsigned_uploads  = 0
```

But it build only for version in debian/changes, but i want build for another versions too.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look at this question that I asked, and got answered:

[PPA & Packaging: Having versions of packages for multiple distros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30145/ppa-packaging-having-versions-of-packages-for-multiple-distros)

You'd have to package multiple times to get each version of Ubuntu, however you can upload a package for one version, then copy it over to each other version.  For instance, I build packages for Lucid, however the same package is compatible with Maverick and later.  As such, using the instructions in the aforementioned link, I copy it over to Maverick and Natty within the PPA, and the system then copies/builds it in the background and then publishes the data to the PPA when its done copying.

Comment: You think that don't need to rebuild package for another distro? I think, that due the fact that versions of libs is different, then binaries should be different too.

Comment: @Anton, It's the source package that is copied. The binary packages are re-built.

Comment: The source package is what is uploaded, the system will build with the relevant libraries on the Launchpad end, you can always specify to rebuild the source packages rather than copying the packages over.

Comment: I see 2 copy options: Rebuild the copied sources, Copy existing binaries. If i coose "rebuild": `The following source cannot be copied: effy 0.0.45-1 in maverick (same version already has published binaries in the destination archive).` What about it?