# How to create a PPA for C++ program?

Tags: application-development, ppa

[image: MyAgenda 1.0 screenshot]

If I have a c++/gtkmm project created with NetBean, how can I make a package to PPA from this?

I have created target files structure (*.desktop, iconfile, ui glade files).

Binary goes to `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/myagenda/bin/myagenda`.

There is also a folder of glade files, that must go to `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/myagenda/bin/myagenda/ui`.

Desktop file goes to `/usr/share/applications/myagenda.desktop`.
 Icon goes to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/myagenda.svg`

As you see, there is only a small number of files.

Now, how to manage all this stuff, to create package on PPA, which *knows* where and how put this files to their targets?

```
├── opt
│   └── extras.ubuntu.com
│       └── myagenda
│           ├── bin
│           │   └── myagenda
│           └── ui
│               ├── item_btn_delete.png
│               ├── item_btn_edit.png
│               ├── myagenda.png
│               ├── myagenda.svg
│               ├── reminder.png
│               └── ui.glade
└── usr
    └── share
        ├── applications
        │   └── myagenda.desktop
        └── icons
            └── hicolor
                └── scalable
                    └── apps
                        └── myagenda.svg
```

**Update:**

1. Created `install` file in `debian` directory with targets:

   ```
   data/myagenda /opt/extras.ubuntu/com/myagenda/bin
   data/ui/* /opt/extras.ubuntu/com/myagenda/ui
   data/myagenda.desktop /usr/share/applications
   data/myagenda.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
   ```

After `dpkg-buildpackage` it builds, but for amd64 architecture. Now, trying to change that to i386.

Comment: I got as far as generating a .deb file. When it came to creating a ppa for it, I got completely lost.

Comment: Create a file named `install` inside debian folder. Setup destination path like this:

Comment: `glade/* /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/myagenda/bin/myagenda/ui`. `icons/*  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps`. `bin/myagenda /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/myagenda/bin/myagenda`. Save the file.Here I am assuming "bin/agenda" is your binary folder. "icons" is your icon folder & glade files located under "glade" folder.Change the folder path accordingly.Then run `debuild`. It will create a deb file. Install the deb file to check everything goes to proper location.

Comment: Architecture is controlled from control file located inside debian folder.Just change it to `Architecture: all` under package name. see this [image](http://i.imgur.com/9bvDf.png) as reference.

Comment: Thanks, but seems, that setting architecture in control file does nothing, if you have 64 bit OS. Still searching for solution. But at least, *.deb file is creating, installing and works all right.

Comment: Try `Architecture: any`.

Comment: Or if you are trying to build it locally,upload the source package to launchpad as described in the answer & let the Launchpad build the source package for you.For any error check build-logs.

Comment: You can find the official documentation at https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating PPA is very simple & at the same time somewhat complex process depending on the complexity of the package( i.e single binary, multiple binary...etc). But for simple application like your MyAgenda creating a PPA is very simple.

First install necessary packages.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts ubuntu-dev-tools debhelper dh-make diff patch cdbs quilt gnupg fakeroot lintian  pbuilder piuparts`. Most of them are probably already installed by default.

Now setup your gpg-key & ssh-key. Follow instruction from [here](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey) & [here](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair).

---

### **STEP1:Layout Of The Source Package**

Now go to your application source folder.Here's your basic source package layout:

```
 MyAgenda-1.0/
    -- data/
          -- myagenda
          -- myagenda.desktop
          -- myagenda.svg
          --ui
             -- myagenda.glade
             -- otherfiles
    -- debian/
        -- changelog
        -- copyright
        -- compat
        -- rules
        -- control
        -- install
```

---

### STEP2:Know your GPG KEY ID & Format

First run:

`gpg --list-keys`. It will give you output something like this:

```
   pub: YOURGPG-KEY
   uid: YOURUSERNAME <YOURMAIL-ID>   #note your username & email.
   sub: --------
```

---

### STEP3:Create Debian Folder

To create debian folder & all other necessary files under debian folder run(**use the same username & email-id from above**):

`DEBFULLNAME="YOURUSERNAME" dh_make -n -s -e YOUREMAIL-ID`. This will help to sign the package with gpg key.

However this wont create the "install" file under debian folder. Create the file manually & save it with following data:

```
        data/myagenda /opt/extras.ubuntu/com/myagenda/bin
        data/ui/* /opt/extras.ubuntu/com/myagenda/ui
        data/myagenda.desktop /usr/share/applications
        data/myagenda.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
```

---

### STEP4: Update Changelog

To update changelog run:

```
dch -i
```

Here is a sample changelog:

```
package (version) distribution; urgency=urgency

 * change details
   more change details
 * even more change details

 -- maintainer name <email address>[two spaces]  Sun, 8 July 2012 18:14:08 +0530
```

Make sure the above format is preserved.When done editing press CTRL+O to write out.Remove
.dch part & overwrite changelog file.Press CTRL+X to exit.

You may want to delete extra .ex files under debian.Enter into debian folder & delete .ex & .EX files.

```
cd debian
rm *.ex *.EX
```

---

### STEP5: Create DEB Package

Then to create deb package run:

`debuild --no-tgz-check`     #Optional.it will not check for the source tarball.

---

### STEP6: Upload To PPA

To upload the source package to a PPA you must run:

```
debuild -S
```

What the -S flag does is tell debuild to build a source package using another script, dpkg-buildpackage, together with fakeroot, which grants us fake root privileges while making the package. It will take the .orig.tar.gz file and produce a .diff.gz (the difference between the original tarball from the author and the directory we have created, debian/ and its contents) and a .dsc file that has the description and md5sums for the source package. The .dsc and *_source.changes (used for uploading the source package) files are signed using your GPG key.

`debuild -S` will create a source.changes file outside your source directory. Go to launchpad & create a PPA. Now upload the source.changes to that PPA((**change the file name accordingly**):

```
dput ppa:YOUR-LAUNCHPAD-USERNAME/myagenda myagenda-1.0-ubuntu1.changes
```

DONE!

---

Notes:

If you want to upload package for several ubuntu versions get help from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30145/ppa-packaging-having-versions-of-packages-for-multiple-distros).

Sources: **[Complete Packaging Guide Wiki](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/)**.

Comment: Thanks. Lanuchpad emailed to me with "accepted". As I see, I must wait to build finish. Anyway, if it works, the ppa is: https://launchpad.net/~piotr-zagawa/+archive/ma

Comment: Aghrr... launchpad build system reports stupid error "pkg-config: not found". What a stupid machine. If I can build that locally, why it does not try to upgrade its config..

Comment: Ok, I found that Build-Depends section in control file needs more information. Entered all required tools/libs: pkg-config (>= 0.26), libgtkmm-3.0-dev (>= 3.0), libunity-dev (>= 5.0), libnotify-dev (> 0.7) and now builds correctly. I didn't know how to update failed uploads, so created many ppa's in tests, but actual one is ppa:piotr-zagawa/ma2. Install with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:piotr-zagawa/ma2. THANKS!

Comment: Glad to know it finally works! Also you can host your code on bazaar. From there ,you can create a recipe from it, which will give you test packages(& debs) daily or on demand.It will just append ~recipe on the version number.Perfect for any kind of testing.This may save from creating multiple PPAs.

Comment: To delete packages from a PPA , go to "view package details" & click on delete packages(Takes time for newly uploaded packages). Select everything & delete.Then you can upload new packages in the same ppa.