# Automated package build service

Tags: package-management, backup, compiling, deb, official-repositories

I´m using Bacula for backuping my servers and clients, but the versions of bacula in the official repository are very old. So I compiled and installed all the components by myself.
But that was very much work and it is also very much work when I want to update the components.

Is there a possibility for an automated build service that creates new packages when a new update of bacula realeases? (maybe in combination with git)
And how can I deploy the created packages with a foreign source to my servers and clients?

greetings 
Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be the creation of a Personal Package Archive (PPA) to Bacula. Basically you provide the source and instructions on how to build Bacula and the packages are built remotely. If you add that PPA to all your machines, after a successfully build they are seen as updates.

I haven't created any PPA, so i cant ensure you this fits exactly you need and how hard it is. You can find more info [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

Another option would be using a continuous integration tool like Jenkins, to constantly watch a repository and when it founds a new version, downloads the sources and build it.

Hope this helps.

#### Edit

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/161212/33871) you can find a very complete answer with the steps needed to create a PPA. Also [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/52478/33871) shows how to automatically checkout code.

Credits to [Khurshid Alam](https://askubuntu.com/users/11112/khurshid-alam) and [George Edison](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison).

Comment: Thx for your reply!
Are there any good tutorials for Jenkins?
greetings

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately i don't have any. The setup is very simple: you just download a .jar, execute it and you got Jenkins running. To get more info checkout their [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Home) and [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project).