# How to package for multiple Ubuntu versions with different package dependencies in a single PPA from launchpad?

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad

I have an existing PPA for a Qt-based application that dates back to `xenial` that I recently updated to support `bionic`.  I did this by just checking in all the changes required for `bionic` (in particular a switch from a third-party Qt PPA to the distro-provided Qt since that the version in the distro is sufficient in `bionic`) as an update to the launchpad project using `bzr`, thus abandoning the older version.

At risk of stating the obvious, to disambiguate the question, my package depends on (and lists as dependencies) the packages of the Qt components that the software uses. In practice this is so that required libraries are installed automatically when the user installs the package from my PPA. In principle I could create a package that did not explicitly depend on anything and the user could manually install the required libraries, but that would defeat the purpose of using a PPA. The third party Qt PPA used in the `xenial` version of my package uses different package names and versions than the distro-provided Qt from `bionic`, so the dependency lists must be different; the package cannot simply be copied to support both distros, and redeploying the package to the other distro with the same `control` file contents will not work.

In principle packages for different Ubuntu versions could need to be maintained in parallel; what is the right way to do that from the packaging, launchpad, and PPA infrastructure? The [`distribution`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-distribution) field in `debian/changelog` allows multiple values, but I don't see a way vary the `control` settings for each.

Comment: Taking a look at the Qt PPA I was using for `xenial`, I see that the author has just created a separate PPA for each combination of distro version and Qt version; obviously I could do that failing anything better.  But on the PPA side at least there appears to be support for having packages for multiple Ubuntu versions published simultaneously.

Comment: The question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/30145/ppa-packaging-having-versions-of-packages-for-multiple-distros is for a more general case, and none of the existing answers on it are appropriate for this question.