# Does debian/changelog have to be release specific?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, source-packages, changelog

I want to create a debian source package that is suitable for multiple OS-releases.

Initially, I was targeting kinetic, and had this changelog format:

```
gfxi (1.3-1) kinetic; urgency=medium

  * Add install and uninstall targets to Makefile.

...
```

From the [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man5/deb-changelog.5.html):

```
 distributions lists one or more space-separated distributions where this version should be
       installed when it is uploaded; it is copied to the Distribution field in the .changes
       file.  distributions must be terminated by a semicolon (U+003B ‘;’).
```

So I changed my changelog entry to:

```
gfxi (1.3-2) jammy kinetic lunar; urgency=medium

  * Add jammy and lunar releases.
...
```

The `debuild -S` command succeeds, but when I upload the debian source package to my PPA using dput, the builder comes back with:

```
Rejected:
Unable to find distroseries: jammy kinetic lunar
Further error processing not possible because of a critical previous error.

gfxi (1.3-2) jammy kinetic lunar; urgency=medium

  * Add jammy and lunar releases.
```

Am I reading the manual incorrectly? Why can't I list the OS releases in my changelog file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly while you're right in that the specification for the changelog allows for it, launchpad PPA builders do not. So you have to craft a separate entry for each release you want to build for, and `dput` each one individually.

This has been asked before on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30145/ppa-packaging-having-versions-of-packages-for-multiple-distros) question, but it's a little buried in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. It is now a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/2009220)